# Angular 4 array in form

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-forms

I am building part of my form with an array of values like so:

```
         <mat-form-field *ngFor="let item of nutrients; let i = index">
            <input matInput type="text" name="{{item.nutrientId}}" placeholder="{{item.nutrientName}} ({{item.nutrientMeasurement}})..." [(ngModel)]="product.productNutrient[i].amount" #amount="ngModel" />
        </mat-form-field>
```

The `product` model:

```
    constructor(
    public productId?: number,
    public productName?: string,
    public comments?: string,
    public manufacturerName?: string,
    public amount?: number,
    public measurement?: string,
    public isAdded?: boolean,
    public isConfirmed?: boolean,
    public productNutrient?: ProductNutrient[])
```

The `product_nutrient` model:

```
constructor(
    public nutrientId?: number,
    public productId?: number,
    public amount?: number)
```

My `component.ts`:

```
product: Product = new Product();
constructor(private api: ApiService, private productService: ProductService) {
   this.product.productNutrient = new Array<ProductNutrient>();
}
```

So what I would like to have the values from my form to be added to `this.product.productNutrient` as an array. However when I open the form right now I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined
```

My complete form for reference:

```
        <form name="addProductForm" #addProductForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addProduct(addProductForm)">

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" name="productName" placeholder="Product naam..." required [(ngModel)]="product.productName" #productName="ngModel" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" name="productDescription" placeholder="Product beschrijving..." [(ngModel)]="product.productDescription" #productDescription="ngModel" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field >
            <input matInput type="text" name="manufacturerName" placeholder="Fabrikant naam..." [(ngModel)]="product.manufacturerName" #manufacurerName="ngModel" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" name="amount" placeholder="Hoeveelheid..." required [(ngModel)]="product.amount" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" name="measurement" placeholder="Meeteenheid..." required [(ngModel)]="product.measurement" #measurement="ngModel" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" name="comments" placeholder="Commentaar..." [(ngModel)]="product.comments" #comments="ngModel" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field *ngFor="let item of nutrients; let i = index">
            <input matInput type="text" name="{{item.nutrientId}}" placeholder="{{item.nutrientName}} ({{item.nutrientMeasurement}})..." [(ngModel)]="product.productNutrient[i].amount" #amount="ngModel" />
        </mat-form-field>

        <button mat-raised-button type="submit" class="secondary-color" [disabled]="!addProductForm.valid">Toevoegen</button>
         <pre>{{addProductForm.value | json}}</pre>
    </form>
```

Comment: What is the `nutrients` you are iterating over? My best guess is that the array you are trying to bind to is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, your Array is not correctly initialized to work like this:

```
this.product.productNutrient = new Array<ProductNutrient>();
```

This creates an empty array: `[]`. But in your template, you use `*ngFor` to render inputs using a different array called `nutrients`, which (I guess) has more than zero items. So, in a stage of rendering, the value of index `i` can be, say, 2, which means

```
product.productNutrient[i]
```

Is undefined. Then you have an `ngModel`:

```
[(ngModel)]="product.productNutrient[i].amount"
```

See, `product.productNutrient[2]` is `undefined`, because `product.productNutrient` is an empty array, so trying to access `product.productNutrient[2].amount` will throw the very error you see in the console. Try instantiating your `product.productNutrient` array in a way that is has as many members as the `nutrients` array, like this:

```
this.product.productNutrient = this.nutrients.map(nutrient => new ProductNutrient(nutrient.id)); // somewhat speculative code, adjust it so it has the same structure as your models do.
```